# SQL Server compatibility level is 2005 (90) but still I am able to use 2012 feature

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, pagination, backwards-compatibility

SQL Server is a 2012 version, but the database compatibility level is set to 90 (SQL Server 2005). But still I am able to use pagination feature (`OFFSET & FETCH NEXT`) in the stored procedure, I am not seeing any error while creating or executing the stored procedure. How is that possible?

Comment: Compat levels are designed to allow older behaviours to carry over into newer databases where those behaviours have changed, they are not general "pretend this is version XXXX and deny newer features" rules.

Comment: @AlexK.So if new features are supported then why merge is failing? When I try to use MERGE statement it gives below error. Why SQL server supports one new feature and doesn't support another?  Error: Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: iirc MERGE should work at level 90, are you sure the syntax is correct? Missing a leading `;`?

Comment: No, I tried with ; also. If I change the compatibility level then exact code works.